# Capture the regex of a target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm not sure if this could be possible using a makefile. I've the following target:

```
build-%:
   ...
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to capture ONLY the string used in the regex.

For i.e.

If I call the target:

```
build-test
```

I'd like to have `test` var available in target to be used. At the moment I've found out only the `$@` but it catch the entire target name

Comment: I think it's the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$*` what you are looking for.

Comment: works like a charm :-)

Comment: Just to be clear, this is _not_ a regular expression, by any stretch.  It's a simple pattern matching character.  GNU make doesn't support regular expressions for target matching.

Comment: @MadScientist _GNU make doesn't support regular expressions out-of-the-box_.

Comment: @Vroomfondel thank you for confirming... what I wrote...??

Comment: @MadScientist I just wanted to hint that with enough effort one could program GNUmake to handle regexps.

Comment: @Vroomfondel If you mean, by hacking the code hard enough then I agree... but this is true of all free software, of course!  I can't think of any way to support regex's in rules without hacking the code though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*automatic variable*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$*` expands to the *stem* (i.e.: the `%` in the pattern rule).

For example, with the following makefile:

```
build-%:
    @echo The stem is $*
```

Then:

```
$ make build-foo
The stem is foo
```